# Python not recognizing pyarrow version properly?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyarrow

When trying to load some parquet files into pandas DataFrame, I get an error claiming that Pyarrow version should be at least 0.16.

If I check the version installed, I confirm that:

```
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.__version__
'0.11.0'
```

However, when trying to install version 0.16, with

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow=0.16
```

I see the following:

```
The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    arrow-cpp-0.16.0           |   py37hf731a26_1        19.8 MB  conda-forge
    aws-sdk-cpp-1.7.164        |       hba45d7a_2         2.1 MB  conda-forge
    boost-cpp-1.72.0           |       h7b93d67_2        16.3 MB  conda-forge
    numpy-1.19.5               |   py37haa41c4c_1         5.3 MB  conda-forge
    pyarrow-0.16.0             |   py37h110162e_2         4.1 MB  conda-forge
    re2-2020.04.01             |       he1b5a44_0         438 KB  conda-forge
    thrift-cpp-0.13.0          |       h5aa387f_5        19.2 MB  conda-forge
    zstd-1.4.4                 |       h3b9ef0a_2         982 KB  conda-forge
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        68.1 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  boost-cpp          conda-forge/linux-64::boost-cpp-1.72.0-h7b93d67_2
  curl               conda-forge/linux-64::curl-7.77.0-hea6ffbf_0
  icu                conda-forge/linux-64::icu-67.1-he1b5a44_0
  pandas             conda-forge/linux-64::pandas-1.2.5-py37h219a48f_0
  python-dateutil    conda-forge/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0
  pytz               conda-forge/noarch::pytz-2021.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
  thrift-cpp         conda-forge/linux-64::thrift-cpp-0.13.0-h5aa387f_5

The following packages will be REMOVED:

  orc-1.6.8-h58a87f1_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  arrow-cpp                        4.0.1-py37hac2aefd_2_cpu --> 0.16.0-py37hf731a26_1
  aws-sdk-cpp                            1.8.186-hb4091e7_3 --> 1.7.164-hba45d7a_2
  grpc-cpp                                1.38.1-h36ce80c_0 --> 1.25.0-h213be95_2
  libprotobuf                             3.16.0-h780b84a_0 --> 3.11.0-h8b12597_0
  lz4-c                                    1.9.3-h9c3ff4c_0 --> 1.8.3-he1b5a44_1001
  numpy                               1.21.0-py37h038b26d_0 --> 1.19.5-py37haa41c4c_1
  pyarrow                          4.0.1-py37he2832ee_2_cpu --> 0.16.0-py37h110162e_2
  re2                                 2021.06.01-h9c3ff4c_0 --> 2020.04.01-he1b5a44_0
  zstd                                     1.5.0-ha95c52a_0 --> 1.4.4-h3b9ef0a_2
```

Why `pyarrow.__version__` returns 0.11 and the terminal ask for a `DOWNGRADE` from 4.0.1?

Your help is much appreciated.

**EDIT** to provide more information:
Doing: `conda list pyarrow` after activating my virtual environment returns:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pyarrow                   4.0.1           py37he2832ee_2_cpu    conda-forge
```

However, if I start python, I check the library is not being load from my vritual environment but from outside:

```
>>> import pyarrow
>>> pyarrow.__file__
'/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py'
```

And if I check my `sys.path`, what I see is the following:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python37.zip', '/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7', '/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

Is it relevant that `'/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` appears before `'/home/myuser/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages'`?

Comment: What is the output of `pyarrow.__file__`?  My guess is that you have version 4 of Arrow installed with conda and version 0.11 installed via pip or some other global location.

Comment: Thanks Pace. That might be right. `pyarrow.__file__` returns `'/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py'`. This is not the directory of the anaconda virtual environment I am working with. How can I fix this without breaking something else?

Comment: You might try setting `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` before you activate your conda environment (and if it works consider putting it in `.bashrc`)  It's discussed a bit [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/394)

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?